# Cycles Procedural Texture Study

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

I've become very interested in procedural textures as of recently. I would like to start building my own library of these textures, so I can easily texture scenes without having to search for copyright free materials to use online.

So far I have successfully recreated two procedural textures, marble and brushed metal, and was even able to come up with a brick texture by myself. It's not up to its full potential yet but I am happy with it.

Anyway, I would really like to keep learning how to make different procedural textures, and was hoping to find some guidance here. If you guys have any experience with this and are willing to give me examples of how to make different textures I would highly appreciate it.

(Just wanted to say that I don't want to copy your node tree to the letter, I would just use them as an example/guidance!)

As of now, I have: Marble, Brushed Metal, and Brick already. 
I am looking to learn how to make: skin, leather, dirt, stone, cracked stone,  reptile skin, tree bark, everything really.

I feel like by recreating and playing with the examples you show me I will be able to figure out the "pattern" I am not getting when it comes to creating a procedural texture.

Here are the images of the textures I have done so far.
[image: Brick Procedural Texture I did myself without guidance]
[image: Brushed Metal Procedural Texture - CG Cookie Tutorial - final]

Comment: Oh, also any guides and tutorials on the subject are highly appreciated as well! Books and websites with the topic too! 
I really appreciate it!

M

Comment: I'd definitely recommend [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0&hd=1#t=60) on manipulating texture coordinates

Comment: Thank you Gandalf3! I'm halfway through it, its really cool stuff. Can't wait to put it into practice. Thanks again!